# c++ OOP design - passing data member to other classes - is it reasonable?

Tags: c++

I have one more question hopefully summerizing my thoughts.

Suppose I have the following 3 classes:

**class Player:**

```
class Player {
private:
    int positionX, positionY;
public:
    void move(Board& b) {
      // player changes its position on the board(move)
      b.removeCharFromBoard(positionX, positionY);
      positionX++;
      positionY++;
      // 'P' indicates a Player in the Board....
      b.insertCharToBoard(positionX, positionY, 'P');
    }
};
```

**class Board:**

```
class Board {
private:
    // BOARD_C and BOARD_R are both "#define ..." for some integer number.
    char board[BOARD_C][BOARD_R];
};
```

**class GameEngine:**

```
class GameEngine {
private:
     Board* board;
public:
     void playTurn(const Player& p) {
        p.move(board);
     }
};
```

is it seem reasonable to you that the GameBoard's playTurn function will call the Player's move function with the parameter "board"?
I need to do it in order to mark in the board data member that the Player has changed his position.
Is it keep the OOP basic rules?

Thank you all,
Syndicator!

Comment: Or `move()` could return the amount of player movement and the board simply updates it...? Up to you

Comment: Yes but this is only a simple example. As It becomes more complex the need to interpret each player action becomes frustrating. I just felt like It doesnt live peacefully together with the OOP rules as the Player class shouldn't know/be familiar with the Board class/object. Am I right?

Comment: In my opinion Player really dont need to know anything about Board, it should only think of itself. I suppose it decouple your design, making it more cohesive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, **in this case** it seems to be reasonable (by "in this case" I mean "considering what I can guess about the semantics of your `GameEngine` and `Board` classes and the nature of their association/aggregation relationship"):

1. Rather use a smart pointer than a raw pointer to hold the `Board` object in `GameEngine`. `unique_ptr` is probably what you want in this case, because all other aliases seems to be just observers and the lifetime of the board object is bound to the one of the `GameEngine` object. However, if shared ownership is needed, opt for `shared_ptr`. Just try not to use raw pointers, `new`, and `delete`, because they lead to buggy code;
2. You still need to provide public functions on the interface of the `Board` class to modify the board, because `Player` won't be able to access its private member variables (and `board` happens to be one).
3. Rather than `#define`s, use `constexpr` values for the sizes of the board (if you are using C++11). You might also want to consider [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html) for creating *safe* bi-dimensional C-style arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll add an arrow, collisions (only between players) and support for 2-3 players (Human and Computer). I just always believed It is really forbidden to let a class like Player to know about its Board. That's one point I can use to deduce for a lot of other Projects where I tried to avoid passing ref of a data member or this in the sake of OOP rules.

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB: this is what I was afraid of :-) Do not "deduce a lot". The fact that a class should not know about the implementation details of another class is a valid principle and it is called *Information Hiding*. You don't want to give that up. However, here it seems to me that the board is a *visible* element of the `GameEngine` class. The pointer is declared as private because you don't want other classes to overwrite that *pointer*, making `GameEngine` point to *another* board. But the *pointed object* itself is supposed to be shared, I guess. [continues...]

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB: [...] So you are not really passing a private member of the class, but rather you are passing an object to which the class is associated through a private member (in your case, a raw pointer, but again, use smart pointers instead). Now if you were giving `Player` a *reference* to that pointer, meaning that you are actually passing *the association itself* and not only the associated object, then you would be breaking the encapsulation principle. So indeed passing a reference or a pointer **to** a member variable is usually not OK. But in this case you are not doing that.

Comment: You really helped me. One line I still try to figure out :"meaning that you are actually passing the association itself and not only the associated object" - oh I understand. If I sent &board. Okay. Thanks you alot!!!!

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB: yes, you got it.

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB: Btw, please try not to generalize too much. If you will find any small universal truth about software design or approach to perfect software design, that will be after *many* years of trying and changing your mind. And most importantly, in spite of what books and teachers say, please don't think that OOP is a perfect paradigm, and don't form in your mind the equation that Object-Oriented = Good: there's *a lot* of Evil in OOP. For instance, many times you should prefer using free (non-member) functions. But OK, this discussion is not for StackOverflow anymore ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is fine. GameEngine will be used as some kind of controller of your game. Thanks to it you can for example filter player movements, check if this kind of move is even possible or do other kind of stuff in case of specific player operations.

Secondly, thnks to this solution you don't have to connect player to specific board, which expands your possibilites of other options like easy transfering players between boards. I think you are on a good way :)

Answer (score 1):

You must think of how your application will change, and what features you would like to introduce. From this code it kind of looks ok, but will it look like that when you will introduce new features?

Other solution is to put into player only moving logic, it will update its positions, then your GameEngine will update board entries basing on all your players current positions. Imaging that with some time you will want to implement collision detection, then after each player has updated its positions or movements, collision detection would take place and correct those movements, and only later on your board would be correctly updated.

Comment: Yes @marcin_j, I will implement collision detection. You are completly right by saying "I suppose it decouple your design, making it more cohesive" but sometimes in big projects when I try to stick this rule too hard I just can't find a solution. That is why I wanted to ask you about a simple example to deduce about big projects. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Many things have already been said, but if I may to add something.

Passing the `Board` (be it `private` or not) to the `Player` is not bad *per se*, and such design is used in several architectures (code taken from SFML 2.0):

```
void Sprite::draw(RenderTarget& target, RenderStates states) const
{
    if (m_texture)
    {
        states.transform *= getTransform();
        states.texture = m_texture;
        target.draw(m_vertices, 4, Quads, states);
    }
}
```

`RenderTarget` is your `Board`. This thing to understand here that you will operate on `Board` **only using its public interface** (to which you have access to). In above code, `draw()` is the method which is used on `target` to force it to draw something.

This whole idea of passing an inner object to a higher level class (like `Player`) can be interpreted as [bridge OO pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern), where there can be several implementations of interface `Board` and several classes can implement `IBoardManipulator` (or something like this).

That said, I would say it's much better to follow the general idea of the game engine which is:

1. Register entities of the game (in this case the player)
2. Capture the player input
3. Digest & react to the player input (request moving the player)
4. Process game logic (check if the player can move to a given location, and if yes - move him)
5. For every registered entity `GameEngine` will call `draw()` passing `Board` as the target which the entities can use.
6. Repeat from step 2

I am not saying that for a simple architecture this is needed, but in the *longer* run it is much easier to manage than to deal with nasty things that each of the `Player`-like classes can do to the `Board`.

Comment: First of all your answer is so clear and so good! Thanks! Second: Quoting from your answer, "5.For every registered entity Board will call draw()" - That means that the Player-like classes will be able to access Board's public functions? In contrary to your summary line where you said "that each of the Player-like classes can do to the Board". Probably I misunderstood bullet NO.5...

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB I fixed my mistake there regarding pt. 5. Entities **will** operate on `Board` as it is passed to them by `GameEngine`. But public interface of `Board` restricts them from destroying all inside.

In the nutshell, `GameEngine` calls every entity by passing the private `Board` which is not normally visible by the clients.

First, life time of `Board` is defined by the `GameEngine` (so you don't have to share the Board between all enitities). Second, you control when the drawing will happen (in case of shared `Board` every entity could draw any time during its own `update()`).

Comment: One more thing if I'm allowed. One important thing I liked in your post is the indicator of the design pattern I'm using (Bridge). I'm reading a-lot of articles, started from Wikipeida and went forward to other sites and I couldn't understand the connection between my code here (passing the Board by reference to the Player class) as indicator to the Bridge design pattern. It is very important to me to be able to understand pricesly what I'm doing and what technique I'm using. As far as I understand Bridge allows an interface class to hold a pointer to an implementation class [Coniune...]

Comment: allowing different implementaion to each derived class. Can you just explain me how it is expressed here? I'm sorry if it a silly question, I just can't understand it.

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB First, look at the wiki page and its diagram. Second, in your code `Board` _could_ be `ConcreteImplementor` class, while `Player` _could_ be the `RefinedAbstraction`. This way by defining the `Implementor` and `Abstraction` interface you could abstract both the implementation of the `Board` and the `Player`. In other words: `Player` wouldn't care what implementation of `Board` is used, and `Board` wouldn't care by what it is used (as `Player` would be the reference to `Abstraction`).

Comment: `class Player : public Abstraction { void update(Implementor& gameArena); }`. `class Board : public Implementor { void drawOnMe(char mark, const std::pair<int, int>& position); }`. The only difference between this code and Wiki is that in Wiki `Implementor` is passed during construction of `Abstraction`, but it doesn't have to be. By not passing it to constructor you control when the `update()` is called, as `update()` can't be called when not having `Implementor`. Obviously you aren't allowed to store the reference to `Implementor` in `Player`.